# Vertically align div's but keeping horizontal position intact

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

From a database I'm pulling a kind of timeline of Div's with a certain starting point and certain end point. Some of them overlap, some of them can be fitted next to each other. 
[image: from Database]

Ultimately I want to slide them together so that it's as compact as possible like this:
[image: what we want to accomplish]

I'm doubting how to approach this challenge: through a server side (php) script or with some javascript floating script thingy. *Or off course a completely different approach*

Could some one push me in the right direction?

**Edit:: 
It's important, as it's a timeline, that the horizontal position of the div's remain the same. So floating all the divs to the left or inline-block them is no option :)**

My database setup:

```
id | name | start | end  
1  | a    | 2     | 7  
2  | b    | 5     | 10  
etc
```

Comment: its called a gantt chart -if you google that you will see some examples in php\js\css etc

Comment: Didn't know there was a name for this kind of charts! Thank you, although the gantt/project chart looks the same it's fundamentally different: you only have one project on one row....

Comment: The color of block depends of what?

Comment: The color is just random :)

Comment: @Dagon "Gantt" should be capitalized, since it's the name of the guy that developed the concept.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the HTML5 canvas? That would massively simplify the problem down to merely "where to put the bars". The problem with a pure CSS solution is one of consistency across browsers. Of course, HTML5's problem is... it doesn't work everywhere. :(

Comment: @stUrb have you checked my fiddle in the answers sections? I used static gray color, but you can easily add any logic of color randomizing. I think my position calculation is the best here plus it works with unlimited data and update() function could be added in 5 minutes.

Comment: Added color randomizing :) checkout http://jsfiddle.net/whHXE/29/

Comment: Although I really like the javascript fiddle things, the PHP and MySQL solution given by @paraoh and UV are the ones I prefer because it's server side! Thank you all for the Effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question sounds very naive but it is actually include some complex elements if needed to be resolved in the most OPTIMISED way.

the quick answer of what I probably would do to generate your display -

1. use the provided function that adds the row number to your table
2. use your PHP code to generate a DIV container with
   style="display:block" for every row
3. inside the row generate appropriate size DIV (end-start * scale)
   with style="display:inline-block; float:left; display:relative" and **(EDIT:)** add transparent DIV elements to compensate for the white spaces you need. (i.e. from 0 to start and from the end to the start of the next DIV)
4. add the name field inside the DIV element

`use mySchema;
drop procedure if exists tileItems;`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE tileItems ()
BEGIN
DECLARE p_id, p_start, p_end, p_row int;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, start, end FROM tasks order by start, id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

drop temporary table if exists tiles;

create temporary table tiles (
row int(11) NOT NULL,
id int(11) NOT NULL,
end int(11) NOT NULL
);
-- row field will indicates the row number the task should apear
OPEN cur1;
next_task: LOOP

FETCH cur1 into p_id, p_start, p_end;
  IF (done) THEN
    LEAVE next_task;
  END IF;
select min(row) from (select row, max(end) me from tiles t2 group by row) t1 
  where me < p_start
  into p_row;


-- take care of row numbering  
IF (p_row IS NULL) then
  select max(row) from tiles
    into p_row;
    IF (p_row IS NULL) then
      SET p_row = 0;
    END IF;
    SET p_row=p_row+1;
END IF;

insert into tiles (id, row, end)
  values (p_id,p_row,p_end);

END LOOP;

-- CLOSE cur1;
-- here is your output, on the PHP/.Net code you should loop on the row 
select tasks.*, tiles.row from tasks
inner join tiles
 on tasks.id = tiles.id
order by tiles.row, tasks.start;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

here is the table I used to check it -

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `name`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 2, 6),
(2, 'B', 5, 7),
(3, 'C', 8, 10),
(4, 'D', 1, 5),
(5, 'E', 6, 7);
```

few words regarding optimisation (one of my favourite subjects :) - 
in this code there is no optimisation, it means that the task will be allocated to the first available line.
in order to minimise the number of lines its possible (but will take some time) to create a function that uses [Heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) method to resolve this problem.

output:

```
id  name    start   end row
4   D   1   5   1
5   E   6   7   1
3   C   8   10  1
1   A   2   6   2
2   B   5   7   3
```

Comment: fixed. I added the output example as well

Answer (score 13):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
  Created using jsbin.com
  Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/udofoq/26/edit
-->
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style id="jsbin-css">div.blue {
    background-color: #a4dcdf;
}

div.orange {
    background-color: #fd9226;
}

div.green {
    background-color: #88b37e;
}

div.yellow {
    background-color: #d8d03f;
}

div.red {
    background-color: #c16558;
}
div.grey {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
div.hours1{
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;//(110-10)
}
div.hours2{
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 50px;
}
div.hours3{
  top: 60px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 50px;
}

div.hours4{
  top: 90px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 70px;
}

div.hours5{
  top: 120px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 30px;
}
div.hours6{
  top: 150px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 70px;
}
div.hours {
  position: absolute;
  height:20px;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  border:white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 2px rgba(00, 00, 00, .2);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 2px rgba(00, 00, 00, .2);
  font: bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  line-height:20px;     
}

button{
    position:static;
    margin-top:200px;
}
.collapse,
.overlap1,
.overlap2,
.overlap3,
reset{
    float:left;
}
</style></head>
<body>
  <div class="hours hours1 orange">A</div>
<div class="hours hours2 yellow">B</div>
<div class="hours hours3 blue">C</div>
<div class="hours hours4 green">D</div>
<div class="hours hours5 red">E</div>
<div class="hours hours6 grey">F</div>
<button class="collapse">collapse</button>
<button class="overlap1">sort</button>
<button class="reset">reset</button>

<script>
data1 = [
  [1, 10, 110],
  [2, 80, 130],
  [3, 120, 170],
  [4, 5, 70],
  [5, 110, 140],
  [6, 130, 180]
];

//just added for console output not needed
var divider="";
for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
  divider += "_";
}

console.log(divider);
console.log("ORIGINAL ARRAY DATA1:", data1);


//add a column to keep track of the row, to start set it to  row 1
data1 = $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
  value[3] = 0;
});

console.log(divider);
console.log("ORIGINAL dataA WITH ADDED COLUMN:", data1);

function timelinesort(dataA){

//make a new Array to store the elements in with their new row number
var dataB = dataA.slice(0, 1);

console.log(divider);
console.log("INITIALIZED dataB WITH FIRST ELEMENT FROM dataA:", dataB);


//initialize the counter
var counter = 0;

console.log(divider);
console.log("INITIALIZED ROUNDS COUNTER:", counter);


dataA = $.map(dataA, function(value1, index1) {

//increment counter with 1 
counter++;

console.log(divider);
console.log("INCREMENTED ROUNDS COUNTER:", counter);


  dataA = $.map(dataA, function(value2, index2) {


    //exclude comparing an element with itself
    if(value2 != dataB[0]) {
      //check to see if elements overlap
      if(value2[2] >= dataB[0][1] && value2[1] <= dataB[0][2]) {
        console.log(divider);
        console.log("Round " + counter  + " from dataA: [" + value2 + "] overlaps with " + dataB[0] + " incrementing row counter with 1");
        //increment the value in column 3 (row counter) of the array
        value2[3]++;
        console.log(divider);
        console.log("Now the dataA has changed to this:", dataA);
        console.log("Meanwhile data1 has changed to this:", data1);
      } else {
        //if no overlap occurs check if the element is not already in the dataB array and if not check if it doesn't overlap with the existing elements
        if($.inArray(value2, dataB) == -1) {
          $.each(dataB, function(index3, value3) {
            if(value3[2] >= value2[1] && value3[1] <= value2[2]) {
              console.log(divider);
              console.log("Round " + counter + " from dataA: [" + value2 + "] overlaps with " + value3 + " incrementing row counter with 1");
              dataB.pop();
              //increment the value in column 3 (row counter) of the array
              value2[3]++;
            } else {
              //if no overlap occurs add the value to dataB
              dataB.push(value2);
              console.log(divider);
              console.log("Added [" + value2 + "] to dataB and now dataB has changed to this: ", dataB);
            }
          });
        } else {
          dataB.push(value2);
          console.log("Added [" + value2 + "] to dataB and now dataB has changed to this: ", dataB);
        }
      }
    }
    return [value2];
  });
  dataA = jQuery.grep(dataA, function(item) {
    return jQuery.inArray(item, dataB) < 0;
  });
  if(dataA.length >= 1) {
    dataB.unshift(dataA[0]);
    dataB = dataB.splice(0, 1);
  } else {
    dataA = [];
  }

});

}
//run the function
timelinesort(data1);

console.log(divider);
console.log("Finally the data1 has changed to this:", data1);


$(".collapse").click(function() {
  $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
    $("div.hours" + (index + 1)).animate({
      "top": 0
    }, "slow");
  });

});

$(".overlap1").click(function() {
  $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
    console.log("div.hours" + (index + 1) + ":" + (value[3]) * 26);
    $("div.hours" + (index + 1)).animate({
      "top": (value[3]) * 26
    }, "slow");
  });

});

$(".reset").click(function() {
  $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
    $("div.hours" + (index + 1)).removeAttr('style');
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I did was collapse all rows onto the first row, then check which ones overlapped with the originals of that row and if so increment the row number over the overlapping ones, then go to the next row and repeat the process until all elements are neatly stacked.

You still have to clean up the javascript/jquery stuff and put it in a nice function or so.  But as proof of concept it seems to work

**working example:**

---

http://jsbin.com/udofoq/26/watch

or

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/7VP5U/

Comment: Adding blocks to html manually isn't really handy in authors use case. IMHO.

Comment: You mean in the css?  It's just a matter of using jquery to place the elements where they are supposed to go.  Or do it in PHP.  That's not the hard part.  That's easy.  It's just the same loop as we do for sorting but with other fields apart from top you would also set left and width.  That's 3 lines extra.  I'll add that when I have some time left

Comment: I will start putting musics in my fiddles from now on ;)

Comment: It's called fiddle for a reason

Answer (score 5):

Check out my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/whHXE/29/). I think it does what you need with unlimeted number of blocks. Blocks data is taken from HTML-table.

JS:

```
var data = [],
    rows = [],
    chart = $('.wrapper-inner');


function DataItem(id, name, start, end){
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
     this.start = start;
     this.end = end;
}

$('.data tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        item = new DataItem( $this.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                             $this.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                             $this.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                             $this.find('td:eq(3)').text() );
        data.push(item);
});

function addRow(){
    var row = {
        el : $('<div class="row"></div>').appendTo(chart),
        positions: []
    };

    rows.push( row );
}

function checkRow(rowId, item){        
    var isRowAvailible = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < +item.end - +item.start; i++){
        if (rows[rowId].positions[+item.start + i]){
            isRowAvailible = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isRowAvailible;
}

function markRowPositions(rowId, item){


    for (var i = 0; i < item.end - item.start; i++){
        rows[rowId].positions[+item.start + i] = true;
    }

}

function addItems(){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function() {addItem(data[i])}, 100 * i);
        })(i)
    }
}

function addItem(item){
    var rowToAdd = false,
        itemEl = $('<div class="item"></div>');

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        if ( checkRow(i, item) ){
            rowToAdd = i;
            break;    
        }
    }

    if (rowToAdd === false){
        addRow();
        rowToAdd = rows.length - 1;
    }

    rows[ rowToAdd ].el.append(itemEl);

        console.log(itemEl.css('opacity'))

    itemEl.css({
        'left': item.start * 30,
        'opacity' : 1,
        'width': ( ( item.end - item.start ) * 30 ) - 2
    });


    markRowPositions(rowToAdd, item);



}

addItems();
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) It wasn't hard actually cos i liked it and i think it works pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could get. It receives a json_string, parse it and generate the results. It's completely dynamic. The elements are fading in the order they are in the json array.

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/isaqol/14/)

Hope this heps:

HTML:

```
    <div id="divHolder">
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="loadChart(json_data1);" value="Load Data 1" />
    <input type="button" onclick="loadChart(json_data2);" value="Load Data 2" />
    <input type="button" onclick="loadChart(json_data3);" value="Load Data 3" />
```

JS:

```
var json_data1 = '[{"id":1,"name":"A","start":2,"end":7},{"id":2,"name":"B","start":6,"end":9},{"id":3,"name":"C","start":8,"end":12},{"id":4,"name":"D","start":0,"end":5},{"id":5,"name":"E","start":7,"end":9}]';

var json_data2 = '[{"id":1,"name":"A","start":5,"end":7},{"id":2,"name":"B","start":6,"end":9},{"id":3,"name":"C","start":2,"end":6},{"id":4,"name":"D","start":2,"end":12},{"id":5,"name":"E","start":1,"end":9}, {"id":6,"name":"F","start":7,"end":11}, {"id":7,"name":"G","start":8,"end":12}, {"id":8,"name":"H","start":2,"end":4} ]';

var json_data3 = '[{"id":1,"name":"A","start":8,"end":12},{"id":2,"name":"B","start":4,"end":10},{"id":3,"name":"C","start":2,"end":4},{"id":4,"name":"D","start":0,"end":7},{"id":5,"name":"E","start":7,"end":11}, {"id":6,"name":"F","start":5,"end":7}]';

function loadChart(json_data){
    var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
    var divHolder = $('#divHolder');
    var maxWidth = $(document).width() - 200;
    var maxHeight = $(document).height();
    $(divHolder).empty();
    var maxEnd = 0;
    var minStart = 0;
    var widthUnit = 0;
    $(data).each(function(){
        if(this.end > maxEnd)
            maxEnd = this.end;
        if(this.start < minStart)
            minStart = this.start;
    });
    widthUnit = maxWidth / (maxEnd - minStart) ;
    var maxItemUnit = maxEnd;
    var rows = new Array();
    $(data).each(function(){
        var added = false;
        var currentObj = this;
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            var toAdd = true;
            //if(widthSum> maxItemUnit              
            var widthSum = 0;
            $(rows[i]).each(function(){
                widthSum += this.end - this.start;
                if(this.end < currentObj.start ||  this.start > currentObj.end){
                    if((widthSum + currentObj.end - currentObj.start) < maxItemUnit) 
                        toAdd = true;
                }                               
                else{
                    toAdd=false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(toAdd){
                rows[i].push(currentObj);
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!added){
            rows[i] = new Array();
            rows[i].push(currentObj);
        }
    });

    $(rows).each(function(){
        var current = this;
        var divMain = $('<div></div>').css('display','block').css('width', maxWidth).css('height', 50)
        $(current).each(function(){
            var div = $('<div></div>');
            div.addClass('item').html('<span class="item-content">'+this.name+'</span>');
            var diff = this.end - this.start;
            div.attr('id', this.id).css('opacity','0').css('left', widthUnit * this.start).width(widthUnit * diff);
            if(diff < (maxItemUnit/3))
                div.addClass('small');
            else if (diff < (maxItemUnit/2))
                div.addClass('medium');
            else
                div.addClass('large');
            divMain.append(div);
        });
        $(divHolder).append(divMain);
    });
    var delayVar = 0;
    $(data).each(function(){
        $('#'+this.id).fadeTo(delayVar, 1);
        delayVar += 300;
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.item{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.item-content{
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.small{
    background-color:#E66C3D;
}
.medium{
    background-color:#DDD634;
}
.large{
    background-color:#3EC043;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take look at the `jQuery.Gantt` plugin
http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function collides($block1,$block2) {
  return ( ($block1['start'] >= $block2['start']) and ($block1['start'] <  $block2['end']) ) or
         ( ($block1['end']   >  $block2['start']) and ($block1['end']   <= $block2['end']) ) or
         ( ($block1['start'] <= $block2['start']) and ($block1['end']   => $block2['end']) );   
}

function FitsInRow ($row,$block) {
    $fits=true;
    foreach ($row as $block1) 
        if (collides($block,$block1))
            $fits=false;
    return $fits;
}

$rows=array();

// $blocks like that:
$blocks[0]['start']=0;
$blocks[0]['end']=10;
$blocks[0]['name']='A';
$blocks[0]['color']='#F00';

$blocks[1]['start']=5;
$blocks[1]['end']=20;
$blocks[1]['name']='B';
$blocks[1]['color']='#0F0';
//etc


foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $i=0;
    while (isset($rows[$i]) && !FitsInRow($block,$rows[$i]))
        $i++;
    $rows[$i][]=$block;
}

echo '<div class="block_outer" style="height: '.(count($rows)*20).'px;">';
foreach ($rows as $nr=>$row)
    foreach ($row as $block)
        echo '<div class="block" style="left:'.$block['start'].'px; width:'.($block['end']-$block['start']).'px; top:'.($nr*20).'px; background-color:'.$block['color'].';">'.$block['name'].'</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

With the following css:

```
.block {
  position:absolute;
  height:16px;
  /* ... */
}
.block_outer {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

I haven't tested it, though.

Edit: I have changed names so it fits the mentioned database setup.

Another edit: Now I have added the outer div so the absolute positions of the inner divs don't break page layout.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was searching for! A nice and clean serverside solution!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried displaying them `inline` with CSS?

```
div.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Where your divs have the class `inline`.

Comment: The problem is they have to stay in the same place horizontally.

Comment: cool question...you should add this *very important* comment you made above to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good case to use:

```
div.hours {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 155px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Of course, replace 100px, 155px, 100px with your values.

Alternatively, you can try to use  tags for the bars, inside  blocks, with position: relative and left/width values.

Comment: O.K. That sounds fair enough, but then I need some kind of algorithm to put some of the bars on one line and others on new ones. And that algorithm is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this, you will need to use `position: absolute` and calculate where the events will be visible in the page, for example: one day full day has `10px height` and `10px width` and we need to add an event at `day 1`, then we check if the `line 1 is empty` or has an event, if it's empty then `put the event there`, else `go to the next line and repeat` until it's allocated in a line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithms, and either implement them yourself (in php or JavaScript), or try to find a suitable ready-made implementation.

Neither CSS properties, nor table layout will solve this problem automatically and flawless.